# Phpmyadmin fail wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I try to install wordpress in local but I have problem with I create database.

[[image]]

I don't know why phpmyadmin doesn't work. I had change some port like database . I change the "mi.ini" file in 3306 in 3307. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might already be running a copy of mysql (or something else) on port 3306. PhpMyAdmin has a config file probably pointing to port 3306 with incorrect credentials.

You need to either alter your mysql config or update your phpmyadmin config (xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php) to point to the new port number (3307 according to xampp) The line will look like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';`